# Validating Multiple Postcodes in an array using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a function which validates postcodes against a regex. The user can either one postcode or multiple postcodes.

When I Enter a single postcode it works fine but when multiple postcodes are entered I just get undefined

Here is my function

```
const validatePostcode = (...postcode) => {
  const postcodeRegex = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{0,1} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
  if (postcode.length > 1) {
    postcode.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item);
      return postcodeRegex.test(item);
    });
  } else {
    return postcodeRegex.test(postcode);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything when `postcode.length > 1`.

Instead, you're iterating over the `postcode` array. The return inside your `forEach` function does nothing.

You need to decide what this function should return. Should it return just a single boolean or an array of booleans?

For a single boolean, you want either [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

An array of booleans would just use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1):

1. `postcode` always present as an array event you didn't pass any params into function.
2. You're iterating over the `postcode` array with `forEach` even though you return the value but the end of `forEach` will return `undefined` instead of `boolean` or `array` as you expected.
3. I used [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method tests whether all elements in `postcode` pass the test. Here it should be `true` for all elements other it will `false` if has any is `false`
4. To avoid [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) return `true` with an empty array then we should check `postcode.length > 0`.

And here is the code:

```js
const validatePostcode = (...postcode) => {
  const postcodeRegex = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{0,1} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
  return postcode.length > 0 && postcode.every(item => postcodeRegex.test(item));
};
```

Comment: Please consider adding additional comments explaining _why_ this is the solution.

Comment: Additionally, Regex solutions are particularly useless without expansion. Code only answers are discouraged on SO, have little to no long-term value, and are considered low quality. Consider adding insight that will enable future visitors to glean insight that can be applied to their own coding issues.

Comment: Thank @SherylHohman for your explanation. I updated the content of the answer

Comment: Thank @DavidL too

Answer (score 1):

forEach method is not meant to return any value: return value of lambda is discarded. This is why you get undefined. The `if... else...` is also useless. forEach works fine with arrays of one element. You need a function that takes in a lmbda and return a value. Depending on what you want it may be `every`, (return true if all postcode matches, see answer by @ttquang1063750) or maybe `map` (return an array of boolean, one for each postcode passed) or `some` (return true if at least one postcode matches)

```js
const validatePostcode = (...postcode) => {
  const postcodeRegex = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{0,1} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
  return postcode.map(item => postcodeRegex.test(item));
};

const validateAtLeastOnePostcode = (...postcode) => {
  const postcodeRegex = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{0,1} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
  return postcode.some(item => postcodeRegex.test(item));
};
```